# best way to transport messages between two different WSO2ESB

Tags: wso2-esb

I'm new to WSO2 so please be forgiving.

My problem is how to connect two separates WSO2 ESB to transport messages between them (a particularly invoke web services seamlessly).

I know it is a very general question and the exact answer may be not possible, but I would like to know in which direction to go. Is it good idea to use JMS transport and e.g ActiveMQ as message broker? And how to test if that connection works?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of solutions, but I think you're right when you speak abour JMS and ActiveMQ. It's very simple to use, just "send" a message to a jms queue with an address endpoint and consume messages from that queue with a JMS proxy.

See https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Java+Message+Service+%28JMS%29+Support